# Using ServletContextListener with Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, servlet-3.0

I want to test my ServletContextListener with embeded jetty. It calls `contextDestroyed` on server stop but doesnt call `contextInitialized` on server start. How can I fix it?

```
Server server = new Server(PORT);
ServletContextListener myListener = ...;
WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
webapp.addEventListener(myListener);
webapp.setServer(server);
server.setHandler(webapp);
server.start(); -> doesnt call myListener.contextInitialized()

server.stop();  -> call myListener.contextDestroyed()
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the context path (and optionally a war): `webapp.setContextPath("/");  webapp.setWar(warURL);`). If not, no context is *really* deployed

Comment: @BGR setContextPath("/") didnt help. I dont have any web.xml file.

Comment: @BGR, But myListener.contextDestroyed() works as designed.

Comment: Does it work if you define myListener in web.xml file ? i.e. use `WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext(path, "/")` instead of webapp.addeventListener

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with Jetty 9.3.10

Have you tried setting extended listener types to true? 
If it is set to false (default), ServletContextListener implementations will not be considered in `org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.Context#checkListener`

```
    webapp.getServletContext().setExtendedListenerTypes(true);
```